# F#: Not understanding match .. with

Tags: f#

I'm messing around with F# and Fable, and trying to test my understanding. To do so, I tried creating a function to calculate e given a certain number of iterations. What I've come up with is

```
let eCalc n =
      let rec internalECalc ifact sum count =
          match count = n with
          | true -> sum
          | _ -> internalECalc (ifact / (float count)) (sum + ifact) (count+1)

      internalECalc 1.0 0.0 1
```

Which works fine, returning 2.7182818284590455 when called with

```
eCalc 20
```

However, if I try using, what I think is, the more correct form

```
let eCalc n =
      let rec internalECalc ifact sum count =
          match count with
          | n -> sum
          | _ -> internalECalc (ifact / (float count)) (sum + ifact) (count+1)

      internalECalc 1.0 0.0 1
```

I get a warning "[WARNING] This rule will never be matched (L5,10-L5,11)", and returned value of 0. (and the same thing happens if I swap 'n' and 'count' in the match statement). Is there a reason I can't use 'n' in the match statement? Is there a way around this so I can use 'n'?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you use a name in a `match` statement, you're **not** checking it against the value assigned to that variable the way you think you are. You are instead **assigning** that name. I.e.,

```
match someInt with
| n -> printfn "%d" n
```

will print the value of `someInt`. It's the equivalent of `let n = someInt; printfn "%d" n`.

What you wanted to do was use a `when` clause; inside a `when` clause, you're not pattern-matching, but doing a "standard" if check. So what you wanted was:

```
let eCalc n =
      let rec internalECalc ifact sum count =
          match count with
          | cnt when cnt = n -> sum
          | _ -> internalECalc (ifact / (float count)) (sum + ifact) (count+1)

      internalECalc 1.0 0.0 1
```

Does that make sense, or do you need me to go into more detail?

P.S. In a case like this one where your match function looks like "x when (boolean condition involving x) -> case 1 | _ -> case 2", it's quite a bit more readable to use a simple `if` expression:

```
let eCalc n =
      let rec internalECalc ifact sum count =
          if count = n then
              sum
          else
              internalECalc (ifact / (float count)) (sum + ifact) (count+1)

      internalECalc 1.0 0.0 1
```

Comment: This is a good explanation, so upvote for that :) I think that a simpler and more idiomatic solution, however, would be to use an `if/then/else` expression.

Comment: Yes, `if/then/else` is better in this case. I wanted to stay as close to the OP's original code as possible to illustrate the difference, but I might as well edit the answer to show the better way as well.

Comment: I think it's fine to show the pattern match syntax as you did, so I'd leave it in the answer, but then maybe also *add* the `if/then/else` option.

Comment: This was very helpful. My original code used the if/then statement, but I wanted something that looked "pretty", or Haskellish (which was my first functional language).