# F#: Remove an element from a self-defined list

Tags: f#

Here is a defined list:

```
 type ilist = 
        E
       | L of int * ilist
```

where the constructor E stands for the empty list and the constructor L builds a list by adding a number in front of another list.

Then one can represent, say, a list with elements 1,4,6,7, in that order, with the ilist value: L(1, L(4, L(6, L(7, E))))

Now I need to implement a remove() funciton to remove all occurences of a element from the list. For example, remove 2 (L(1, L(2, L(3, L(3, L(2, E)))))) is L(1, L(3, L(3, E))).

Here is my solution:

```
let rec remove (x:int) (l:list)=
    match (x, l) with
    | (_, E)->E
    | (_, L(x, l1)) -> remove (x) (l1)
    | (_, L(y, l1)) -> L(y, remove (x)(l1)) // Warning: This line will never be matched
```

As you see, the third case will never be matched. How can I deal with the case such that I can maintain the element in the list if it is not x?

The right solution:

```
let rec remove (x:int) (l:ilist) =
    match l with
    | E->E
    | L(y, l1) when x==y -> remove x  l1
    | L(y, l1) -> L(y, remove x l1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [F#: Not understanding match .. with](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711655/f-not-understanding-match-with)

Answer (score 3):

Very loosely speaking, in pattern matching, you give the thing behind the match statement a new name. `match (x, l)` means: you take your arguments, break it up in pieces, assign new names. In your second match clause, you essentially say: Ignore the first part of the tuple. For the list, give the head element the name `x`, and the rest the name `l1`. Now this new name `x` shadows your argument `x`. In particular, this is not interpreted as "If the first element of the list is `x`, then do..."

This also explain why your third match clause is never matched: It does not matter whether you give the head element the name `x` or `y` - it matches the same kinds of lists.

Note also that you have `_` for all matches clauses, you can change to `match l with` and drop all the `_`. What you're after is something like

```
match l with
| E -> E
| L(head, rest) when head = x -> rest
| L(head, rest) -> L(head, remove x rest)
```

Here's also a really nice [article about pattern matching.](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/match-expression/)