# Unable to generate random number F#

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I am working on a small project and am trying to learn F# the functional way ,for some strange reason I am unable to generate a random number and as such unable to get a random date. here is my F# code

```
let IfancyHerList = [("Sara",1); ("Saima",2); ("Zoe",3);("Scarlett",4);
("Jennifer",5);("Sandra Bullock",6)]

let MyGirlFriend  = List.pick (fun funToNight  ->
                     let n = rand.Next(10)
                     match funToNight with                    
                     | (value,n ) -> Some value
                     |_ -> None) IfancyHerList
printfn "Your date for tonight is %s lucky fella" MyGirlFriend
```

The let n = rand.Next(10) does generate a random number but not in match block

any suggestion would be most welcome

thanks

Comment: That's because this API to random numbers is incompatible with functional programming. Your pseudorandom number generator has implicit state, that in a proper functional program you'd have to pass as an argument to `next`, and get a number and a new modified state in a `pair<>` as result. You shouldn't want to do that in first place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [F#: Not understanding match .. with](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711655/f-not-understanding-match-with)

Comment: You accepted my answer, but David Raab's answer was much more complete. I feel like you should un-accept my answer and accept his instead, since that's the one you commented on saying how much it helped you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code doesn't do what you expect it to do. Pattern Matching is technically the opposite of constructing data. It just decompose/de-construct data.

What you do here:

```
match funToNight with                    
| (value,n ) -> Some value
|_ -> None
```

has the following meaning:

1. Check if `funToNight` is a tuple.
2. Assign the first value of the tuple to `value`
3. Assign the second value of the tuple to `n`

It seems what you expected was:

1. Check if the second value of a tuple is what is inside `n`

And that isn't how Pattern Matching works.

You can add conditionals like comparing a value with a pre-defined variable by adding a `when` clause to the Pattern Matching. Like this:

```
match funToNight with
| (value,x) when x = n -> Some value
| _ -> None
```

But in my opinion, your case is exactly a use-case where Pattern Matching don't make sense to begin with. You want to check if the second entry is your random number, so use an `if` statement instead.

```
let MyGirlFriend  =
    List.pick (fun funToNight  ->
        let n = rand.Next(10)
        if   (snd funToNight) = n
        then Some (fst funToNight)
        else None
    ) IfancyHerList
```

instead of `fst` and `snd` you also can do it in the lambda.

```
let MyGirlFriend =
    List.pick (fun (name,nr)  ->
        let n = rand.Next(10)
        if   nr = n
        then Some name
        else None
    ) IfancyHerList
```

This is the general solution to pick that also works with tuples of other sizes. `fst` and `snd` only work with tuples that has exactly two elements.

Besides that you probably want to use `List.tryPick` instead of `List.pick`. `List.pick` throws an exception if it cannot find an element. On top variables should start with a lower-case. Upper-case values are used for Types/Classes.

So here is a complete working example:

```
let rand = new System.Random()

let ifancyHerList =
    [
        ("Sara",1); ("Saima",2); ("Zoe",3); ("Scarlett",4);
        ("Jennifer",5);("Sandra Bullock",6)
    ]

let myGirlFriend =
    List.tryPick (fun (name,nr)  ->
        let n = rand.Next(10)
        if   nr = n
        then Some name
        else None
    ) ifancyHerList

match myGirlFriend with
| Some name -> printfn "Your date for tonight is %A lucky fella" name
| None      -> printfn "You don't have a date tonight!"
```

## Addendum

Your `List.pick` call returns quite a lot `None` and doesn't pick an entry. The reason is that you generate the random number inside the lambda function you pass to `List.pick`.

Your current "flow" of your code is like this. You go through the list. First picking `("Sara",1)`. You generate a random, let's say `5`. `1` and `5` doesn't match so the next entry `("Saima", 2)` will be used. But then you generate again a new random number, let's say `3` and the next entry is picked because `3` and `2` are not equal. This can go on without every picking any entry. Even if you change the random generation to `rand.Next(6)`.

So a general advice is that you shouldn't add side-effects to lambda expressions. I assume you want to generate one random number and then pick it from the list. Its easy to change by extracting the random call outside the lambda.

```
let myGirlFriend =
    let n = rand.Next(10)
    List.tryPick (fun (name,nr) ->
        if   nr = n
        then Some name
        else None
    ) ifancyHerList
```

So a general advice, avoid side-effects in Higher-Order functions.

Comment: David can we please swap brains for a bit, you have explained this so well for the first time in 12 weeks I have to understand what functional programming is all about. thank you. problem solved.

Comment: @WaheedRafiq I added an Addendum to another problem.

Answer (score 5):

Your real issue isn't with random numbers at all, it's with your `match` statement. You misunderstand how it works. Short version: `match (whatever) with (value, n) -> ...` doesn't do what you think it does: it always matches, and assigns the names `value` and `n` to the two parts of whatever tuple you matched against.

The longer version is that you're making the same mistake as [F#: Not understanding match .. with](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38711655/2314532), so I'll just point you to that question to read the more in-depth answer.